# Moment generating function of a compound Poisson process

Tags: moment-generating-functions, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to prove an equality about the generating function of a compoung Poisson process and I don't know how to continue it.

I'm using this definition:

> A process $\{X_t, t\geq 0 \}$ is a compound Poisson process if we can write it as $$X_t=\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}Y_i$$
>   where $\{N_t,t\geq 0 \}$ is a Poisson process and $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a family of random independent v. with the same distribution wich are independent from $\{N_t,t\geq 0 \}$ as well.

I'm proving that

> $m_{X_t}(u)=\exp(\lambda t (m_{Y_1}(u)-1))$

And here it is my aproche:

\begin{align}
          m_{X_t}(u) & = E(e^{uX_t}) = E(\exp(u\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}Y_i)) \\
           &  &  \\
           & = \sum_{m=1}^\infty E\left(\exp \left(u\sum Y_i \right)  \right) \cdot P(N_t=m)\\
           &   \\
           & = \sum_{m=1}^\infty E\left(\exp \left(u\sum Y_i \right)  \right) \cdot \dfrac{(\lambda t)^m e^{-\lambda t}}{m!} \\
           &   \\
           & =  \sum_{m=1}^\infty E\left( e^{uY_1} \right)^m \cdot \dfrac{(\lambda t)^m e^{-\lambda t}}{m!}\\
           &  \\
           & =  \sum_{m=1}^\infty m_{Y_1}(u)^m \cdot \dfrac{(\lambda t)^m e^{-\lambda t}}{m!}\\
           &   \\
           & =  \sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{m\ln(m_{Y_1}(u))} \cdot \dfrac{(\lambda t)^m e^{-\lambda t}}{m!}
        \end{align}

I know I have to be very close of the solution but my brain don't work. Maybe a silly thing is missing. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty m_{Y_1}(u)^m \cdot \frac{(\lambda t)^m \mathrm e^{-\lambda t}}{m!}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(m_{Y_1}(u)\lambda t)^m}{m!}\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}=\mathrm e^{m_{Y_1}(u)\lambda t}\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}$$
(Watch out for the summations, which should start at $m=0$, not $m=1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Bring the exp(−λt) term outside the summation from the 2nd last step and recognize the remaining part of the summation as an infinite series for exponentials.

Comment: Thank you! It was a silly thing in fact :P